# jQuery autoComplete implementation

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm very new to JS and jQuery.  I have an array of Events like so:

```
data {...}
[0]: {...}
[1]: {...}
[2]: {...}
[3]: {...}
...
[40]: {...}
length: 40 

data[0] {...}
__type: "acme.acmeSystem.EventManagement.Event"
Amenity: {...}
DateFrom: "/Date(1326952800000)/"
DateTo: "/Date(1326952800000)/"
Title: "Birthday party"
Description: "Friends coming over for a party."
Food: false
Id: 3
IsPrivate: true
Notes: ""
NumberOfPeople: "Less than 10"
Status: {...}
TimeFrom: "8:30 AM"
TimeTo: "11:30 AM"
User: {...}
```

How can I tie this array to the autocomplete plugin so that someone only has to start typing the Title of the event in the textbox to find the matching events?  When it displays the list of events in the dropdown, they can click on the event of their choice and it takes them to the details page for that event (example: mywebsite.come/Events/EventDetails.aspx?ID=50).

I tried doing this:

$("#EventsSearch").autocomplete({
source: data
});

I simply want to do something like this but also when one of the events is clicked in the dropdown, it takes them to the details page.  Thanks.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap ur autocomplete suggestions in anchor tag `<a href='desired url'>autocomplete suggestion</a>`. So that when they are clicked page redirect to  ur desired location.